# Multiple SwiftUI views sharing data members

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

Here's my situation.... I have a view called SwiftUIView() - it contains a picker and a textbox

You can see it here:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class section_array: ObservableObject {
let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
var first_value = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
var second_value = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @Binding var master_sections: [ContentView.my_Section]
    @ObservedObject private var first_value: section_array = section_array()
   // @Binding var current_section: ContentView.my_Section
    @State private var comment: String = String()
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Picker(selection: self.$first_value.first_value , label: Text("Subsection")) {
                 ForEach(0 ..< self.master_sections.count) {
                 Text(self.master_sections[$0].name)
                       }}
                 TextField("Enter your comment.", text: $comment)

                   }
                  }                
                }
```

Attempting to utlizie this view here:

```
      ForEach(master_subsections) { result in
      SwiftUIView(master_sections: self.$subsections)
                }
```

Causes the right amount of SwiftUIViews to appear, however, they all seem to share the same $comment and $first_value, these are private fields - I need them unique to each occurance of the SwiftUIView().

Comment: You pass same `SwiftUIView(master_sections: self.$subsections)` for each iteration, so what would you expect?

Comment: Is there a way to pass self.$subsections as a object that isn't a reference?